# Position a relative layout below a listview element

Tags: java, android

```
RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.catalogParent);

View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.detailedcatalog, null);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,view.getId());

item.addView(child, layoutParams);
```

Above is the code for placing a layout below a listview element. The view.getId() function is always returning a -1. The relative layout is being inflated programmatically during runtime.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
int position, long arg3) {
...}}
```

The view object is obtained from the onItemClick function. Can you please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you want ? do you want to add relative layout when ever you click on ListView row ? is this so

Comment: yes, the detailedcatalog.xml(relative layout) is the view that I want to inflate.

Comment: view.getId() return the id of listview row'id which you click, you require the listview's id in layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,view.getId());

Comment: Your question is not so clear. The view provided to the listener will be the same as `lv`, whatever that is.  `View.getId()` returns -1 when the view has no id.  So the answer lies in the value of `lv`.

Comment: where you want to add child below list row or below list ? where is this layout on the screen catalogParent ?

Comment: I think it is making some sense, as I am inflating the whole listview elements one at a time, each element will not have an id, I guess?

Comment: So do you have any alternative solutions to this?

Comment: @Dheeresh Singh I want to add the child below the list row, the row on which the click event has occurred.

Comment: where is this layout on the screen catalogParent in which you adding new view?

Comment: I am a bit confused, the parent layout is a listview and when I click any element in this listview, a new relative layout(detailedcatalog.xml) gets inflated below the element which has been clicked.

Comment: the catalogParent is the main relative layout which contains the listview.

Answer (score 0):

So I used view.getLocationInWindow(location), where location is an int array of size two, which gave me the position on the screen of the listview element and then I placed the relative layout on the screen accordingly, using the co-ordinates obtained from location.